# How paint a pixel using click on a PIL image with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Im trying to paint a pixel on a PIL image on click, im using Tkinter to display the image and i can get the coordinates of the clicked pixel already, but i cant show the painted pixel on the screen

This is the tkinter class where i display the PIL image

```
class selectPoints(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    alto = int(master.alto)
    ancho = int(master.ancho)
    master.geometry(f'{ancho+50}x{alto+100}')
    canva = Image.new('RGB', (ancho, alto), (255, 255, 255))

                # This is the function where i get the click coordinates        
        def callback(event): 
            color = (0, 255, 0)
            canva.putpixel((event.x, event.y), color)
            print ("clicked at: ", event.x, event.y)
        
    tkpic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(canva)
    label = tk.Label(self, image=tkpic)
    label.image = tkpic  # Save reference to image
    label.pack()
    label.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
```

This is the look of the image, and the clicked coordinates on the console:
[Tkinter window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFWIA.png)
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a21U.png)

I tried to re-apply the image on the tkinter window every time i click, but the image stays as original, without any change

```
def callback(event):
    color = (0, 255, 0)
    canva.putpixel((event.x, event.y), color)

    tkpic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(canva)
    label = tk.Label(self, image=tkpic)
    label.image = tkpic  # Save reference to image
    
    print ("clicked at: ", event.x, event.y)
```

Comment: Inside the function you create a new `PhotoImage` (which is on the right track) but python garbage collects it when the function is done. Instead of `label = tk.Label(self, image=tkpic)`, use `label.config(image=tkpic)`.

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks! Replacing this line worked, this is not the first i have problems with the garbage collection on this program, theres any clear way to recognise if a element its being garbage collected by Python?

Comment: The rule is: if python can't access the object (from where your code execution is at) then it should be garbage collected. In your `callback` you create a variable named `label` and `tkpic`. You assign `tkpic` to `label.image`. Then after the function ends you loose your reference to `label` and `tkpic` so `python` garbage collects `label.image` as well. After that the `PhotoImage` is deleted from `tkinter`'s memory and can't be displayed. My explanation skills are terrible so if you have further questions, research it/ask a new stackoverflow question.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using PIL? It seems like what you want to do can more easily be done with a `tk.PhotoImage` object.

Comment: @TheLizzard Hmmm i understand the root of the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: @BryanOakley Its a school project, the objective is to make a program similar to MS Paint, the closest thing I found was PIL but I will try your alternative

Comment: @TheLizzard It is not garbage collection because the parent of the label has reference to  it.  It is that the newly created label is invisible because no layout function is applied to it.

Comment: @acw1668 Welp I didn't notice that and I forgot that each widget stores it's children in a dictionary so the label isn't garbage collected. If you write an answer with that explanation, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be creating a new instance of the image. Create the image once, and then modify it. The changes will automatically appear in the window.

Also, it doesn't look like you need to use PIL. The standard `tk.PhotoImage` class has the ability to change individual pixels of an existing image. Using it will reduce the complexity of the code.

You may still want or need to use PIL in order to resize the image or save it in a format not supported by tkinter, but my recommendation is to only use PIL where you need to use PIL, and use the built-in functionality when possible.

Here's a small example showing how to create the image once, and then modify it using the `put` method on the image. This example also shows how to fill a whole area, by calling `put` to initially fill the whole image with black. It's also possible to fill an area with an array of colors (ie: to simulate different paintbrush shapes) but I won't show how to do that here to keep the example simple.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Drawable(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, width=100, height=100):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._image = tk.PhotoImage(master=self, width=width, height=height)
        self.configure(image=self._image)
        self._image.put("#000000", to=(0,0,99,99))

        self.bind("<1>", self._click_callback)

    def _click_callback(self, event):
        color = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (0, 255, 0)
        self._image.put(color, to=(event.x, event.y))

root = tk.Tk()
draw = Drawable(root, 100, 100)
draw.configure(bd=2, relief="groove")
draw.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
tk.mainloop()
```

---

Example screenshot after clicking randomly a dozen times:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the advise! Im required to use PIL for academic purposes, but this answer is very interesting, i didnt know about the capabilites of tkinter to do something like this, i'll try i paintbrush idea :)